# Iteratively add <option> elements to select list in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React.PureComponent to make dozens of select lists in several nested components. For this example, assume `this.props.options` looks like this:

```
[
    "",
    "01 - Jan",
    "02 - Feb",
    "03 - Mar",
    "04 - Apr",
    "05 - May",
    "06 - Jun",
    "07 - Jul",
    "08 - Aug",
    "09 - Sep",
    "10 - Oct",
    "11 - Nov",
    "12 - Dec"
];
```

Here is my PureComponent:

```
class SelectElement extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            optionList: []
        };
    }
    render() {
        try {
            this.props.options.forEach(option =>
                this.state.optionList.push(new Option(option, option))
            );
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("optionList is a : " + typeof (this.state.optionList));
            console.log("Exposing optionList globally!");
            GLOBALOPTIONLIST = this.state.optionList;
        } 
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <select className="form-control" name={this.props.inputName}>
                    // this just shows [object HTMLOptionElement]
                    {this.state.optionList.toString()}
                    // this throws an error "Objects are not valid as a React child"
                    {this.state.optionList}
                </select>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Am I using `new Option(option, option)` incorrectly? I also tried raw string substitution, e.g.:

```
this.state.optionList.push(`<option value={option}>{option}</option>`)
```

But this renders a string inside select tags in the DOM...

Answer (score 0):

This seems stupid, but it worked:

```
this.state.optionList.push(<OptionElement value={option} text={option}/>)


class OptionElement extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return(  
            <option value={this.props.value}>{this.props.text}</option>
        );
    }
}
```

Would love to know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just pushing an option element into your array?

```
this.props.options.forEach(option =>
  const optionElement = <option value={option}>{option}</option>;
  this.state.optionList.push(option);
);
```

Then render them with `{this.state.optionList}`.